# Why Percent-Padded CSS List Item Changes Width on Click?

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I've tried googling and searching here, but can't understand what's happening.

I want menu list items to be % based, I could give them % width, but then they all would be same width. I want it look nicer and have borders within distance relative to text width if that makes sense. So I decided to use table cells and % padding. It all looked nice until I started clicking links. Then width of each list item starts changing. No idea why it's happening and how to solve this. hope you can help.

```css
* {
 margin:0;padding:0;
}
#nav {
 display: table;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FF9;
}
#nav ul {
 display: table-row;
}
#nav ul li{
 display:table-cell;
 margin:0;
 padding:1em 3%;
 border-color:#000;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:0 1px 0 0;
     }
#nav ul li:last-child{
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li><a href="#">Products</a></li><li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li><li><a href="#">Support</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok turns out simply removing padding stops that glitch from happening. And as previous commentator suggested using em works great. Not sure why I decided to use %. But nevertheless, it's odd that glitch happens after a click.